# Cognos 11 Analytics on premises - save generated html code when running a report

Tags: html, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I'd like to know if there's a way to view and save the html code that's generated behind the scenes of a cognos report when it's being run.  We are using Cognos 11 on premises.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "behind the scenes".  If you want to view the source code for the HTML for just the report (and not the entire Cognos session):

- Run as...
- HTML Run in background
- Delivery (choose an option)

  - Send report by email and Attach the report
  - Save report as an external file

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.  Let me be more specific:  We want to view the HTML source code that's generated for the report that we're running. For example, we run as ...PDF.  We want to view the HTML code that creates the PDF report.